# Can't pickle <type 'cStringIO.StringI'> using Databricks PySpark parallelization

Tags: python, amazon-s3, pickle, pyspark

I have read questions asking things about the multiprocessing module for serialism on workers where a `cStringIO.StringO` can't be pickled. However, I have a `cStringIO.StringI` (notice the last capital 'I', for 'input' I presume). I have no idea how to fix this. Im trying to map a series of S3 bucket keys to Pdf objects using PyPDF2. So far so good if I do this on my local system, but if I do this on the workers it goes wrong. This is the code with the error message:

```
def createPdfObject(pdfIdKey):
  pdfId = str(pdfIdKey[0])
  pdfKey = pdfIdKey[1]
  pdfKey.get_contents_to_filename(pdfId+'.pdf')
  try:
    pdfObj = pdf.PdfFileReader(pdfId+'.pdf')
  except pdf.utils.PdfReadError as ex:
    pdfObj = None
    message = "Traceback: {0}\nException: {1} for PDF id: {2}. Arguments:\n{3!r}\nIgnoring this file. Returned NoneType"\
      .format(traceback.format_exc(), type(ex).__name__, pdfId, ex.args)
    print message
    pass
  return (pdfId, pdfObj)

pdfDataRDD = filesRDD.map(lambda x: createPdfObject(x))
```

The error without the full traceback on the Databricks server (which is super long):

```
PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'cStringIO.StringI'>: attribute lookup cStringIO.StringI failed
```

Comment: `cPickle` fails to serialize both `cStringIO.StringI` and `cStringIO.StringO` objects, and `multiprocessing` uses `cPickle`.  You are out of luck, apparently, because the `map` is baked into the `PyPDF2` `filesRDD` object.  If you can monkeypatch the `filesRDD` object to use the fork of `multiprocessing` called  `multiprocess` , then you might be able to do what you want.  `multiprocess` uses `dill`, which can serialize the objects you want to pickle.

Comment: You are right! Thank you. I decided to just process the full file in one map call on the workers, and just return a dict with the extracted data! :)

Comment: You may want to post an answer to your question.